# Como abrir a biblioteca de mídia do WordPress pelo tinyMCE?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce-4

Estou tentando criar um shortcode para embutir arquivos de áudio na página, e prefiro não usar o shortcode padrão do WordPress pois preciso de outros parâmetros.

Uso um script básico para abrir uma janela do tinyMCE, que contém uma caixa de texto ("audio_url") e um botão. Ao clicar no botão, preciso abrir a biblioteca de mídia, para nela procurar ou enviar arquivos de áudio, que quando inseridos, preencherão o campo de texto com o URL do arquivo.

Isso é o que tenho (não funciona como preciso, veja mais adiante):

```
{ // essa é só uma opção de shortcode numa listbox que guarda todas
    text: 'Audio Shortcode',
    onclick: function() {
        var win = editor.windowManager.open( {
            title: 'Insert Audio',
            body: [
            {type: 'textbox',
            name: 'audio_url',
            id: 'audio-url',
            label: 'File...',
            value: '',
            },
            {type: 'button',
            name: 'find',
            text: 'Find...',
            onclick: function() {
                var audiofield = win.find('#audio-url');
                var myurl = tb_show("Audio search", "media-upload.php?type=audio&height=700&width=600&TB_iframe=true");
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    url: myurl,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 600,
                    resizable: 'yes',
                    close_previous: 'no',
                    oninsert: function ( url ) {
                        audiofield.value = url;
                    }
                }
        )},
    },              
],
onsubmit: function( e ) {
    editor.insertContent( '[audiomb src="' + e.data.audio_url + '"]');
    }
});
} },
```

O que tentei aí foi criar uma janela do tinyMCE contendo a thickbox padrão do WordPress, para buscar o arquivo e quando inserir (oninsert), preencher a caixa com o URL.

Não funciona porque o iframe do tb_show carrega atrás da janela do tinymce, e uma janela vazia (a última editor.windowManager.open) na frente de todas. Como posso fazer a janela da biblioteca de mídia ser carregada corretamente ao clicar no botão, para então inserir a mídia e preencher a caixa? Ou o tinyMCE 4 tem um jeito melhor de fazer isso funcionar?
Obrigado!

Comment: Opa, tudo bem? Dá uma olhada nisso: http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/

Comment: Sei que o botãozinho ali no TinyMCE fica bem melhor, mas, nossa, ia ser muito menos dor de cabeça fazer um Custom Meta Box. Dá até pra inserir algo completamente customizado [entre o input box do Title e o textarea do Content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23036236/1287812).